# How can I start over a offset(); function repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement, offset

so I've spent a lot of time making this code, it works, but the only bug that I can't fix is to make it circling repeatedly. Could anyone give some suggestion about the problem and it's solution?

```
 <h1 id="heading">Hello</h1>

 var offsetLeft = 0;
 var offsetTop = 0;
 var offsetLeftReverse = 200;
 var offsetTopReverse = 200;

 var moveHeading = function () {
     $("#heading").offset({ left: offsetLeft, top: offsetTop});

    if(offsetLeft < 200){
        offsetLeft++;
    } else if (offsetTop < 200){
        offsetTop++;
    }
 };

var moveHeadingReverse = function () {
     $("#heading").offset({ left: offsetLeftReverse, top: offsetTopReverse});

    if(offsetLeftReverse > 0 ){
        offsetLeftReverse--;
    } else if (offsetTopReverse > 0){
        offsetTopReverse--; 
    } 
 };

var engine = function () {
   if ( (offsetTop === 0 && offsetLeft <= 200) || (offsetTop < 200 && offsetLeft === 200) ){
        moveHeading(); 
    } 
   else if ( (offsetTopReverse === 200 && offsetLeftReverse <= 200) || (offsetTopReverse <= 200 && offsetLeftReverse === 0) &&
            ( offsetTopReverse != 0 || offsetLeftReverse != 0 ) ){
       moveHeadingReverse();
       console.log("reverse");
       console.log(offsetTopReverse,offsetLeftReverse);
    } 
}

var start = setInterval(engine, 5);
```

Comment: Can you add a little detail of what your code is supposed to do exactly? One can go through the code to understand but I don't think anybody will be willing to do that.

Comment: It should move 200px to right,200px to the bottom, 200px to left and 200px to where it started.And the problem is that I can't make it move automatically it makes only one circle.

Comment: I think in that case you have to make a call to `moveHeading` somewhere inside `moveHeadingReverse` when the reverse movement is complete and there's nothing to do

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Yes I tried a lot of stuff and the most convenience was to add an else statement with offsetLeft = 0;
 var offsetTop = 0;
 var offsetLeftReverse = 200;
 var offsetTopReverse = 200;

Comment: like refreshing the data of the coordinates for the heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: You have to handle the case where the offsets are 0 , then reset your variables to start state and then call engine again (that did the intervall for you):

```
var engine = function () {
   if ( (offsetTop === 0 && offsetLeft <= 200) || (offsetTop < 200 && offsetLeft === 200) ){
        moveHeading(); 
    } 
   else if ( (offsetTopReverse === 200 && offsetLeftReverse <= 200) || (offsetTopReverse <= 200 && offsetLeftReverse === 0) &&
            ( offsetTopReverse != 0 || offsetLeftReverse != 0 ) ){
       moveHeadingReverse();
       console.log("reverse");
       console.log(offsetTopReverse,offsetLeftReverse);
    } else if ( offsetTopReverse === 0 && offsetLeftReverse === 0) {
        offsetLeft = 0;
            offsetTop = 0;
            offsetLeftReverse = 200;
            offsetTopReverse = 200;
    }
}
```

check out the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yfp9f70g/

Comment: Hey, thanks very much, my main idea was just like that but instead of else if I've been using else but it didn't work.Thanks.

Comment: Glad this could help you